# Deleting nullptr - performance overhead?

Tags: c++

Operator delete checks itself if the pointer is nullptr. Is there any performance overhead when calling delete on a nullptr without checking it yourself?

```
delete ptr;
```

or

```
if (ptr != nullptr) delete ptr;
```

Which of the above executes faster if ptr is nullptr?

Comment: The latter is redundant, so potential speed differences aside, it's worse.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As usual, it depends on the compiler.

I use MSVC, which compiles both these lines to exactly the same code.

The rules say that if the pointer is null, the delete has no effect. So if you don't check that, the compiler has to anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitively a case of over optimization.  On any modern processor, the difference is a few nanoseconds.

By doing the check, the code avoids the overhead of a call (to the delete library routine).  In 99% of the cases, the slight extra complexity of the source code (braces, potential typo writing `!=`, etc.) is more of a problem than the extra execution time.

Comment: The check has to be in the generated code, before the call to the library `::operator delete()`, since the compiler isn't allowed to call the destructor, either, if the pointer is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't any overhead when you don't check if the `ptr` is `nullptr`.

If you make a check manually, the same check is done twice, although this is negligible, comparing to the cost of system call, you could expect if the `ptr` is not null.

Comment: Also, if you already use C++11, maybe consider not using delete at all and use smart pointers instead?

Comment: C++11 isn't necessary -- Boost has had good smart pointers for years. :-]

Comment: Of course! But when they lie just under you hand, you have no more excuses for not using them in most standard cases :)

Answer (score 2):

> Which of the above executes faster if ptr is nullptr?

Assuming your check doesn't get optimized away, the top one would be faster. If it does get optimized away, neither would be faster. *Leave it to the compiler.*