# Do I need to initialize with nullptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor, nullptr

The other day I did a C ++ interview. I had to do code review...

This is not the example from interview but it is a good example of my question

```
class A{
    public:
    A(int n) : m_n{n}, m_v{new char[n]}{
    //do something
    }
    ~A(){
        if(m_v != nullptr)
        {
            //here I said it should be checked and initialized with nullptr
            delete []m_v;
            m_v = nullptr;
        }
    }
    private:
    int m_n;    
    char *m_v;

};
```

The interviewer said it was useless to do that. Nothing happens if you delete nullptr. I expected it to be undefined behavior. So my question Is a good practice to do that or not ? (or is it mandatory)

Comment: Well, I'd say that's a case for coding style.

Comment: `delete[] m_v;` properly handles the nullptr case.  Setting `m_v = nullptr;` is of no actual value since the object is just about to be a non-object... however, I do that in my dev debug code because it helps to expose dangling pointers.  (Not that I'd ever have a dangling pointer.)

Comment: Your interviewer was right. This is completely useless. In other situations this may not be, but in this case it is 100% useless. It is logically impossible, in a well-defined C++ program, to get the result of `delete`ing the pointer that that above code has set to a `nullptr` value. Therefore, this is logically useless. Again, this statement applies explicitly, and specifically, to this exact use case and only to this exact use case, and to nothing else.

Comment: Some references: [Deleting nullptr - performance overhead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741520/deleting-nullptr-performance-overhead) * [Is it still safe to delete nullptr in c++0x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731331/is-it-still-safe-to-delete-nullptr-in-c0x) * [What C++17 standard say about calling delete on nullptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47354881/what-c17-standard-say-about-calling-delete-on-nullptr) * [Is it worth setting pointers to NULL in a destructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060006/is-it-worth-setting-pointers-to-null-in-a-destructor)

Comment: Your dtor is private in your example. So, you cannot define `A a;`. You only can define `A *a;`. and in this case you cannot call delete on `a` because the dtor is private.

Answer (score 4):

Both, checking for `nullptr` **and** assigning `nullptr` after the `delete` are not needed and hence should not be there in this example.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete) on `delete` (emphasize mine):

> For the first (non-array) form, expression must be a pointer to an object type or a class type contextually implicitly convertible to such pointer, and its value must be **either null** or pointer to a non-array object created by a new-expression, or a pointer to a base subobject of a non-array object created by a new-expression.
>
> [...]
>
> If expression is not a null pointer and the deallocation function is not a destroying delete (since C++20), the delete expression invokes the destructor (if any) for the object that's being destroyed, or for every element of the array being destroyed (proceeding from the last element to the first element of the array).

Calling `delete` on a `nullptr` does nothing.

Assigning `nullptr` after `delete` in your example is pointless unless there is other code in the destructor that checks `m_v` for being a `nullptr` or not. After the destructor is run `m_v` does not exist anymore.

PS: This really isn't about style. Code that has no chance to do anything useful should not be written. Really no offense, but doing the check for `nullptr` and setting the pointer to `nullptr` can be considered as [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Comment: What if the `m_v` variable is deleted externally (e.g. through `A a; delete a.getM_V();`)? In that case it should be checked, no?

Comment: @Gupta no, in that case checking for `nullptr` wont help a bit. A pointer does not magically change to `nullptr` when someone else deletes the pointee

Comment: @Gupta anyhow that is not possible in the example. `m_v` is private and from outside there is no way to access the character array created in the constructor

Comment: Yeah, and the dtor is private also, so it will never be called ;)

Comment: @Gupta actually that also prevents to create an object on the stack. You can only `new` it and leak it. That comment should rather be for the OP, not my typo ;)

Comment: Sorry about destructor it was private but that was my misstake.